# Find the equation from the given equation in which leading term has c0-efficient $1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Find the  equation obtained from $5x^3-7x^2+8x-9=0$ into one in which the co-efficients of leading term is  unity and the others are integers.

*Below I am showing my attempt*:

Applying the transformation $x\mapsto x+h$,then $f(x)=5x^3-7x^2+8x-9$ transforms into $f(x+h)=5(x+h)^3-7(x+h)^2+8(x+h)-9$

$ =5(x^3+h^3+3x^2h+3xh^2)-7(x^2+h^2+2xh)+8(x+h)-9$.

But this is not giving anything feasible as the leading term of $x$ must have co-efficient $1$.

How can I arrive at it?Should I use any alternative transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Then, divide it by $5$ to obtain: $$f’(x+h) = x^3+x^2(3h-\frac75) + x(3h^2-\frac{14h}{5}+\frac85) +(h^3-\frac{7h^2}{5}+\frac{8h}{5}-\frac95)$$

Now, note that $f’(x+h)$ is [monic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monic_polynomial) and the coefficients of every power of $x$ should $\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Sorry,I don't get why the co-efficient of every power of $x$ is in $\Bbb Z$.Can you elaborate?Also how should I choose $h$?

Comment: How do you choose $h$ such that $3h-\frac{7}{5} \in \Bbb Z$

Comment: @New_User Note that $3h - \frac75 = k$ where k is an integer. So, $h = \frac{1}{3}[k + \frac75]$.

Comment: I really don't understand this.If $k=1$ then $h=\frac{2}{3}$ then how do the co-effiecents alll become integers

Comment: We need to find the exact equation in the question after the transformation

Comment: @New_User Note that you have got the value of h when k =1 as 2/3. Now, put h=2/3 in (3h^2-14h/5+8/5), if that is an integer, ok. Otherwise, proceed with k =2, and find the value of h and so on.

Comment: @New_User Basically, the value of h you get for different k should give integer values for all coefficients.

Comment: So I need to do these for all $k\in \Bbb Z$.Won't that be a never ending process